# Can't reordering commits with rebase -i produce incorrect code at times?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Though haven't tried personally, still my intuition says that reordering commits with git interactive rebase can produce both syntactically and semantically incorrect code at times. The final result may vary if the orders are shuffled. One trivial example could be if both the commits `A` and `B` make different changes on the same line of the same file, then shuffling these commits can hurt. Of course, if commits are mutually exclusive and independent of each other, no such scenario would occur. However, a mindless reordering may produce unusable code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would go a step further and say that a mindless reordering _will_ produce unusable code.  But this is why you need to pay close attention to the conflicts that arise when switching the order of the `A` and `B` commits.  Nothing about Git is inherently evil, and there are certainly legitimate use cases where one might want to do an interactive rebase to change the order of commits.

Comment: If you "mindlessly" resolve a conflict, of course you're going to destroy code; if conflicts could be resolved mindlessly, git would do it automatically. The question is only interesting if we consider only reorderings that don't involve conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something?

Short answer: No and yes.

No because you're right: if you re-order commits randomly, you may end up with something not so nice.

Yes because in your example, if you switch 2 commits which impact the same line, then Git will detect a conflict and won't go on until you declare solved it. ie: in such a trivial case, Git won't produce corrupted code.
(And for more complex cases, well, it never hurt to have a non regression suit)

To put it in a nutshell: don't re-order commit randomly: do it only when you know what you're doing. And everything will go fine!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

If you are worried the result of the rebase is not identical to how it was before, try `diff`ing with the previous state, which can be found using `git reflog`.